# Accessing WMS.GetMap as anonymous?

Tags: geoserver, wms, getmap

I am using GeoServer 2.6.2.

I have a problem with the WMS service.

to authenticate the service wms configure the following rule in " List of access to services"

wms.GetMap  ROLE_AUTHENTICATED

but the response this url

http://localhost/geoserver/xxxx/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=xxxx:clientes&styles=&bbox=.......&width=378&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

is

**Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Cannot access WMS.GetMap as anonymous**

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261945/cannot-access-wms-getmap-as-anonymous-in-geoserver

It is another problem, but read the last comment on the page and try to configurate the "Allowing anonymous read-only access" (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html)